# How to deploy JBoss SOA platform on Openshift?

Tags: jboss, openshift

How can i deploy JBoss SOA platform on Openshift? Do anyone has idea about same?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it cleared that as of now it is not possible to host JBoss SOA 5.3 on Openshift as OpennShift supports JBoss EAP 6 while JBoss SOA supports EAP version 5.